# Не открывает выпадающий список на страницe, в WebView

Tags: android-studio, webview, android-webview

Предыстория. `WebView` открывает обыкновенную мобильную версию сайта, там есть страница, на которой расположен выпадающий список (скрин1). Я перехожу туда и нажимаю открыть список, но он не открывается. Точнее сказать на эмуляторе все нормально, а вот на реальном устройстве не хочет работать. Может есть какой-то код дополнительный? JS включен если что.

[image: скрин1]

Нужно чтобы открывалось так:

[image: скрин2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно есть такая бага в браузерах на Android? `<select>` не будет отображать элементы выбора, если есть `border-radius` и / или `border`. (часто обсуждается на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dropdowns+are+not+working+in+android)) Используйте приведенный ниже фрагмент кода, чтобы поправить стили CSS и правильно отобразить , как нестилизованый элемент.

```
<script>
$(function () {
  var nua = navigator.userAgent
  var isAndroid = (nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 && nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Chrome') === -1);
  if (isAndroid) {
    $('select.select_class_name').removeClass('select_class_name').css('width', '100%');
  }
})
</script>
```

## UPD#1 как сделать вставку JS  и CSS в WebView?

```
private void inject(String filename) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(filname);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();

        // preserve non-english letters
        String uriEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");

        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(uriEncoded.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        if (filename.endsWith(".css"))
        {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                    "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                    "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
                    "style.type = 'text/css';" +
                    "style.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                    "parent.appendChild(style)" +
                    "})()");
        }
        if (filename.endsWith(".js"))
        {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
                "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
                "script.innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(window.atob('" + encoded + "'));" +
                "parent.appendChild(script)" +
                "})()");
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

И добавляем вызов этого метода после загрузки страницы:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                inject("injectStyle.css");
                inject("injectScript.js");
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Как мне это использовать? Этот код как-то можно вставить в приложение?

Comment: @Сергей а сайт не ваш?

Comment: Нет, к сожелению не мой